# How to use .proj file with TFSBuild 2013 ? ItemNotMappedException There is no working folder mapping for TFSBuild.proj

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfsbuild

I'm trying to reuse my TFSBuild.proj file from TFS Build 2010 to TFSBuild 2013 but am getting the error
ItemNotMappedException There is no working folder mapping for /TFSBuild.proj.

I've set the "Projects to Build" in the Build Definition to my .proj file. The .proj file does not live in the same directory as the code being build 
i.e.
$(SourceDir) is set to: $/Scrum2012/src-Corrib: 
and the "Projects to Build" is set to:
$/Scrum2012/TeamBuildTypes/xBuildDev/TFSBuild.proj

Does the .proj file need to be added to some configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution.
Add the location or parent directory location of the .proj file to the "Working Folders" in the Build Definition
e.g.
 $/Scrum2012/src-Corrib: $(SourceDir)
 **$/Scrum2012/TeamBuildTypes: $(SourceDir)\TeamBuildTypes**